# issue detecting text box contents and converting to local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```
// Create an event listener to save the entry when it changes
// (i.e. when the user types into the textarea)
 function saveEntry() {
    // TODO: Q1(c)(iii) Task 1 of 2
    // Save the text entry:
    // ...get the textarea element's current value
    //    (getting HTML input values is in Block 2 Part 2 Section 6)
   document.getElementById("addTextEntry").value.addEventListener("click", localStorage);  
    // ...make a text item using the value
    //    (demonstrated elsewhere in this file)
    // ...store the item in local storage using the given key
    //    (local storage is in Block 3 Part 5)
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.item);

}
```

I can't get the text area element to store into local storage can anyone give any pointers as I am at a standstill and scratching my head.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>My Erehwon Diary NOTCODE123</title>
<meta name="author" content="Stephen Rice" />
<!-- Set viewport to ensure this page scales correctly on mobile devices - 
->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tma03.css" />
<!-- Set demo data -->
<script src="tma03-demo.js"></script>
<!-- Start TMA03 application -->
<script src="tma03.js"></script>
  </head>
   <body>
  <h1>My Erehwon Diary NOTCODE123</h1>
  <main>
  <section id="text" class="button">
    <button type="button">Add entry</button>
  </section>
  <section id="image" class="button">
    <button type="button">Add photo</button>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" />
     </section>
    </main>
  </body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    localStorage.removeItem("")
</script>
</html>
```

this is the HTML if anyone needs more info please let me know I have tried some of the code people have sent and nothing is working as of yet and tank you in advance

Comment: This doesn't look like a good-faith effort. Have you tried writing a solution yourself (other than the fake code above that's just describing the question and not making an attempt at solving it)?

Answer (score 1):

You're setting your `click` event to call `localStorage`, but there is no `localStorage` function.

Without seeing your HTML I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
 document.getElementById("addTextEntry").addEventListener("click", saveEntry); 
 
 function saveEntry(e) {
    const addTextEntryEl = e.currentTarget.value;
    // You will need to add code here to do what you want and then call your local storage below with the right parameters you're setting up here
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.item);
}
```

Comment: this is the html

Answer (score 0):

Your event listener is a bit off. This is how you can add an event listener to a textarea (note the `input` event listener):

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("add-text-entry")[0].addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(event.target.value);
})
```

```html
<textarea class="add-text-entry"></textarea>
```

You can simply replace the `console` statements with `localStorage.setItem(key, value.);`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are correctly getting the value of the textbox. It should already be a string, so there is no need to process it further with JSON methods:

```
const value = document.getElementById("addTextEntry").value;
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.addEventListener` takes in the event type and a listener. A listener is a function. `localStorage` is not a function. `JSON.item` is also invalid.

```
document.getElementById("addTextEntry").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var item = document.getElementById("addTextEntry").value;
  localStorage.setItem(key, item);
});
```

You can read more about [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: I keep getting document is not defined. any thoughts

Comment: Where are you inserting the script? It should be at the end of the body, but inside of it.